# Replace few keywords from SQL search result

Tags: sql, sql-server

A column with varchar string has been selected from a table.
There are some special characters that require to be replaced for displaying purpose.
What is the best way to do it?

```
select top (1) timestamp, url from dbo.transcationtable
```

and transaction table contains url which have %20, %22 etc for spaces and other characters.
Need to replace them with physical space and other symbol

Comment: Thank you. I have made an example hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `UrlDecode` you can try to write a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UrlDecode(@url varchar(3072))
RETURNS varchar(3072)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @count int, @c char(1), @cenc char(2), @i int, @urlReturn varchar(3072) 
    SET @count = Len(@url) 
    SET @i = 1 
    SET @urlReturn = '' 
    WHILE (@i <= @count) 
     BEGIN 
        SET @c = substring(@url, @i, 1) 
        IF @c LIKE '[!%]' ESCAPE '!' 
         BEGIN 
            SET @cenc = substring(@url, @i + 1, 2) 
            SET @c = CHAR(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
                                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1) as int) 
                                ELSE CAST(ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 1, 1)))-55 as int) 
                            END * 16 + 
                            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1) LIKE '[0-9]' 
                                THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1) as int) 
                                ELSE CAST(ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@cenc, 2, 1)))-55 as int) 
                            END) 
            SET @urlReturn = @urlReturn + @c 
            SET @i = @i + 2 
         END 
        ELSE 
         BEGIN 
            SET @urlReturn = @urlReturn + @c 
         END 
        SET @i = @i +1 
     END 
    RETURN @urlReturn
END
GO
```

use like

```
Select top (1) timestamp, UrlDecode(url) from dbo.transcationtable
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a58dafd018bc7b206eab9d2fdd0e975)

Refer link:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/peter_debetta/archive/2007/03/09/t-sql-urldecode.aspx